# C++ Template TypeName as Friend

Tags: c++, templates

Need to make the specialization a friend... but getting error...

```
template<typename foo>
class bar
{
    friend class foo;
};
```

error C2649: 'typename': is not a 'class'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that class names are also type names, and that you don't need to specify `class` when using it as a type name.

Because `foo` already is a type name, the same applies here and you don't need the `class` keyword:

```
friend foo;
```